# AlertDialog issue on Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, dialogfragment

I ran into some strange UI issues while trying to display a custom content `AlertDialog`. The dialog asks the user to enter a name and it doesn't allow him to move forward without doing so. It is also the first thing that the user sees when the activity starts.

Sometimes, right after the application gets restarted - let's say I press the home button when the dialog is opened and then I reopen the app, the `AlertDialog` is being displayed as it should be but the parent activity's layout is not being loaded correctly. It actually keeps the layout from the previous Activity that the user was seeing. Even stranger, this layout is almost always displayed backwards. You can probably see that better in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO9LK.png). Behind the dialog it should be a blank white layout but instead there's a reverted "snapshot" of the launcher activity from the Settings app.

As the official documentation suggests I am wrapping the `AlertDialog` in a `DialogFragment`.

```
public class NicknamePickerDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public static final String TAG = NicknamePickerDialog.class.getSimpleName();

    public interface NicknameDialogListener {
        void onNicknamePicked(String nickname);
        void onPickerCanceled();
    }

    private NicknameDialogListener mListener;
    private EditText mNicknameEditText;
    private Button mPositiveButton;

    public void setNicknameDialogListener(NicknameDialogListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Set the title
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.pick_nickname);

        // Inflate the custom content
        View dialogView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.nickname_dialog_layout, null);
        builder.setView(dialogView);

        mNicknameEditText = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.nickname);

        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.great, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onNicknamePicked(mNicknameEditText.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onPickerCanceled();
                }
            }
        });

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                mPositiveButton = dialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                mPositiveButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });

        mNicknameEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                mPositiveButton.setEnabled(s.length() != 0);
            }
        });

        return dialog;
    }
}
```

This is the `Activity` code

```
public class ChatActivity extends Activity implements NicknamePickerDialog.NicknameDialogListener {

    private String mNickname;
    private TextView mWelcomeTextView;
    private NicknamePickerDialog mDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chat_activity_layout);

        mWelcomeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
        mDialog = new NicknamePickerDialog();
        mDialog.setNicknameDialogListener(this);
    }

    private void showNicknamePickerDialog() {
        mDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), NicknamePickerDialog.TAG);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNicknamePicked(String nickname) {
        mNickname = nickname;
        mWelcomeTextView.setText("Welcome " + nickname + "!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPickerCanceled() {
        if (mNickname == null) {
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mNickname == null) {
            showNicknamePickerDialog();
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

At first I suspected that it probably happens because I am calling the `DialogFragment`'s `show` method inside the activity's `onCreate()` callback (as it might be too soon), but postponing it to as late as `onResume()` does not solve the problem. This issue also occurs on orientation changes, leaving the background behind the dialog black. I am sure I am doing something wrong but I really can't find out what that is.

Answer (score 0):

I am seriously not getting that what you are trying to do. but one thing you have done the wrong is that.

Do overide method OnCreateView() in class  NicknamePickerDialog and do the below

```
// Inflate the custom content
        View dialogView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.nickname_dialog_layout, null);
        builder.setView(dialogView);

        mNicknameEditText = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.nickname);
   mNicknameEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                mPositiveButton.setEnabled(s.length() != 0);
            }
        });
return dialogView;
```

also your alert dialog will not work . better create buttons and title you can in onCreateDialog().

dialog.setTitle(R.string.pick_nickname);

Hope this will work.

Comment: I really did my best to explain the problem and I honestly don't think that you have to read the code more than once in order to clearly understand what's going on. I am using a subclass of `Fragment` that is specialized in working with Dialogs and according to the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#DialogFragment), this is the right way to do it. Also, the dialog itself works!